# CSS transition performance on ios

Tags: css, ios, performance, css-animations

I have the problem that the transition really slow down when the animated container have a more complex HTML structure. Animating an empty container is really smooth but after adding more data into it performance really sucks. I know about hardware acceleration adding `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` to the animated element but this seems not help with complexer DOM structures.

Are there any resources that describe what will effect the performance of CSS transition on iOS beside `translate3d`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your container is within the screen or is bigger than screen?

I was making a book type app where each page was of the size of the screen and contained complex dom structure. As i put more pages in the dom, the performance becomes slower for navigation and transitions inside pages. But removing the pages from the dom which are not in screen and rendering them only when page appears or is to be appear improved the performance much.

So try to remove the elements or make them `display:none` which are not visible to the user, it may improve your performance.

And also here is very good resource for improving the performance
http://www.mikedellanoce.com/2012/09/10-tips-for-getting-that-native-ios.html